# WPCLI command not working correctly when run as CronJob

Tags: linux, wordpress, cron, wp-cli

I am trying to run the cronJob as for wpcli. But the output is not as expected.

For example :

when I run the command wp --info on terminal I get the following output.

```
$ ./wp-cli.phar --info
OS:     Linux  #1 SMP Tue Jul 23 08:31:06 EDT 2019 x86_64
Shell:
PHP binary:     /usr/php
PHP version:    7.3.16
php.ini used:   /usr/php/php.ini
WP-CLI root dir:        phar://wp-cli.phar/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli
WP-CLI vendor dir:      phar://wp-cli.phar/vendor
WP_CLI phar path:       /home/user
WP-CLI packages dir:
WP-CLI global config:
WP-CLI project config:
WP-CLI version: 2.4.0
```

But if I run the same using CronJob and redirect the output to a log file, it is not the same.

CronJob command used :

```
./wp-cli.phar --info >> ~/info.log
```

Output I get :

```
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

If I append the another command along with it, its out is received properly.

For example :

```
./wp-cli.phar --info >> ~/info.log && date >> ~/info.log
```

Output :

```
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Sat Apr 11 12:45:15 CEST 2020
```